# Ruby dot notation to nested hash keys

Tags: ruby, recursion, nested, traversal

What's the best way of converting a dot notation path (or even an array of strings) into a nested hash key-value? Ex: I need to convert `'foo.bar.baz'` equal to `'qux'` like this:

```
{
    'foo' => {
        'bar' => {
            'baz' => 'qux'
        }
    }
}
```

I've done this in PHP, but I managed that by creating a key in the array and then setting a tmp variable to that array key's value by reference so any changes would also take place in the array.

Comment: Sorry, but it each time I tried to answer the question you posted on my now-deleted answer brought on a headache.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
f = "root/sub-1/sub-2/file"   
f.split("/").reverse.inject{|a,n| {n=>a}} #=>{"root"=>{"sub-1"=>{"sub-2"=>"file"}}}
```

Comment: A small thing I like here is that you didn't make `'file'`the initial value of the object which would become a hash.

Comment: you need to add `{}` to inject to make it work with single values, e.g `base.split(".").inject({}) { |acc, el| { el => acc } }
=> {"js"=>{}}`

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably use recursion. For example:

```
def hasherizer(arr, value)
  if arr.empty?
    value
  else
    {}.tap do |hash|
      hash[arr.shift] = hasherizer(arr, value)
    end
  end
end
```

This results in:

```
> hasherizer 'foo.bar.baz'.split('.'), 'qux'
 => {"foo"=>{"bar"=>{"baz"=>"qux"}}}
```

Comment: How would this method look if I wanted to perform this action on an already existing hash? I need to run this on each file I encounter so that all the files end up in a single structured hash at the end that represents the directory tree.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can you provide an example of the input you'd receive?

Comment: Let's say I have a variable 'tree' (Hash) that I ultimately want everything to be in. And I have the following filepaths:

    /foo/bar/baz/qux.log
    /foo/bar/nginx.log
    /foo/bar/baz/api.log

and I want the result to be:

    {
    'foo' => {
        'bar' => {
            'baz' => {
                'qux.log',
                'api.log'
            },
            'nginx.log'
        }
    }
    }

I understand the format may have to be different slightly for the hash (numeric indexes for files, etc.), but that's kinda what I'm looking to achieve.

Comment: I could even just have 'files' be a the key and their values be nil, that'd be easy to identify them vs folders who's key would be another hash

Comment: @alex-phillips, I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56810091/3380256) that operates on a new or existing hash. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I like this method below which operates on itself (or your own hash class). It'll create new hash keys or reuse/append to existing keys in a hash to add or update the value.

```rb
# set a new or existing nested key's value by a dotted-string key
  def dotkey_set(dottedkey, value, deep_hash = self)
    keys = dottedkey.to_s.split('.')
    first = keys.first
    if keys.length == 1
      deep_hash[first] = value
    else
      # in the case that we are creating a hash from a dotted key, we'll assign a default
      deep_hash[first] = (deep_hash[first] || {})
      dotkey_set(keys.slice(1..-1).join('.'), value, deep_hash[first])
    end
  end
```

Usage:

```rb
hash = {}

hash.dotkey_set('how.are.you', 'good')
# => "good"
hash
# => {"how"=>{"are"=>{"you"=>"good"}}}

hash.dotkey_set('how.goes.it', 'fine')
# => "fine"
hash
# => {"how"=>{"are"=>{"you"=>"good"}, "goes"=>{"it"=>"fine"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar when I wrote an HTTP server that had to move all the parameters passed in the request into a multiple value hash which might contain arrays or strings or hashes...

You can look at the code for the [Plezi server and framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/5fe7682a48b85fe5b57fe42caf1450e71091e856/lib/plezi/server/http.rb#L18-L29)... although the code over there deals with values surrounded with `[]`...

It could possibly be adjusted like so:

```
def add_param_to_hash param_name, param_value, target_hash = {}
    begin
        a = target_hash
        p = param_name.split(/[\/\.]/)
        val = param_value
        # the following, somewhat complex line, runs through the existing (?) tree, making sure to preserve existing values and add values where needed.
        p.each_index { |i| p[i].strip! ; n = p[i].match(/^[0-9]+$/) ? p[i].to_i : p[i].to_sym ; p[i+1] ? [ ( a[n] ||= ( p[i+1].empty? ? [] : {} ) ), ( a = a[n]) ] : ( a.is_a?(Hash) ? (a[n] ? (a[n].is_a?(Array) ? (a << val) : a[n] = [a[n], val] ) : (a[n] = val) ) : (a << val) ) }
    rescue Exception => e
        warn "(Silent): parameters parse error for #{param_name} ... maybe conflicts with a different set?"
        target_hash[param_name] = param_value
    end
end
```

This should preserve existing values while adding new values if they exist.

The long line looks something like this when broken down:

```
def add_param_to_hash param_name, param_value, target_hash = {}
    begin
        # a will hold the object to which we Add.
        # As we walk the tree we change `a`. we start at the root...
        a = target_hash
        p = param_name.split(/[\/\.]/)
        val = param_value
        # the following, somewhat complex line, runs through the existing (?) tree, making sure to preserve existing values and add values where needed.
        p.each_index do |i|
             p[i].strip!
             # converts the current key string to either numbers or symbols... you might want to replace this with: n=p[i]
             n = p[i].match(/^[0-9]+$/) ? p[i].to_i : p[i].to_sym
             if p[i+1]
                   a[n] ||= ( p[i+1].empty? ? [] : {} ) # is the new object we'll add to
                   a = a[n] # move to the next branch.
             else
                 if a.is_a?(Hash)
                    if a[n]
                       if a[n].is_a?(Array)
                            a << val
                       else
                            a[n] = [a[n], val]
                       end
                    else
                       a[n] = val
                    end
                 else
                    a << val
                 end
             end
        end
    rescue Exception => e
        warn "(Silent): parameters parse error for #{param_name} ... maybe conflicts with a different set?"
        target_hash[param_name] = param_value
    end
end
```

Brrr... Looking at the code like this, I wonder what I was thinking...